# MS Teams CallRecord: where is the first CallSegment and how I can access it?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

in the call seen in the next image, the 2nd user has 2 Call segment but in the call record on the last one is shown.
[image: teams call /admincenter view)]

If my mind is correct i left the call and joined later again.
See parts of the JSON-File of the CallRecord above.

[image: part of the callrecord]

What happened to the 1st segment and how I can access it ?

I have no idea what goes wrong here. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is that the same session because the particpants are the same.
So if an user joined or left the chat only then a new session will be created. 
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

In your picture, it looks like there are 5 sessions (the second person has two) - and your call has indeed 5 sessions.

Comment: Thankfor correction. It seems I posted something wrong. I would clarify cases for multiple segments, but I would understand how multiple segments work. On mistake I postet this, it t seems i found no data with multiplye segments. doe s anyone know scenarios for multiple segments?

Comment: Nearly all calls have multiple segments, as you have multiple people speaking, bots, queues, auto-attendants... all at the same time.